# Correct technique to join tables?

Tags: sql, plpgsql

I'm trying to get the NUMSESSION value out of the membership_benefit table. My function has a benefit ID and a membership ID as parameters, and membership_benefit needs both of these values otherwise it will return multiple rows.

Here's the gist of the function

```
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION benefit_when(_benefitid integer, _membershipid 
 integer) RETURNS text AS $$
 DECLARE
     bfrec record;
 BEGIN
     if _membershipid is not null then
         select 
             benefit.*,
             membership_benefit.numsession as numsession
         from benefit 
             left join membershiptype on benefit.membershiptypeid=membershiptype.id
             left join membership_benefit on _membershipid = membership_benefit.membershipid
         where benefit.id=_benefitid
             AND (membership_benefit.membershipid is null or membership_benefit.membershipid = _membershipid);`
```

The numsession value is not being returned correctly. If I print the value of the two parameters and simply query the DB it returns the right one, but not in this function. Are you allowed to use a variable to join like I am here, and if not, would there be a better way to get the number I'm looking for with the two parameters I have?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why left join `membershiptype` table. You never use it. It also seems very very strange that you are left joining a table, but your ON clause shows no relationship to either of the other tables already joined. Please share some sample data and your desired results.

Comment: @JNevill, sorry, I had forgotten a where clause. 
The second part of your comment is one of the two roots of my question, does joining a table like with a variable instead of another's column actually work like you would expect it to?

Comment: By putting `membership_benefit.membershipid = _membershipid` in your WHERE clause you are essentially turning that last oddball join into an INNER JOIN. You have the same condition in both the ON and WHERE and that's just really strange. Again, please share some sample data for these tables and your desired result. It's not clear what you are trying to do and your query is quirky.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  You don't even explain what you want the function to do.

Comment: Your function is incomplete. The essential end is cut off. We don't get to see how you return anything. Please provide the *complete* function code (minimal example) so we can make sense of it. And always your version of Postgres, too.

Answer (score 0):

change your query:

```
select 
         benefit.*,
         membership_benefit.numsession as numsession
     from benefit 
         left join membershiptype on benefit.membershiptypeid=membershiptype.id
         left join membership_benefit on _membershipid = membership_benefit.membershipid
     where benefit.id=_benefitid
```

into this:
     `select    benefit.*,
             membership_benefit.numsession as numsession
         from benefit 
             left join membershiptype on 
      benefit.membershiptypeid=membershiptype.id
                      where benefit.id=_benefitid
           and  _membershipid = membership_benefit.membershipid`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want `numsession`, I'm not sure why you are doing an outer join.  Is this what you really want?

```
select mb.numsession
from membership_benefit mb
where mb.membershipid = _membershipid and
      mb.benefitid = _benefitid;
```

If you always want the row for the benefit, along with this information:

```
select b.*, mb.numsession as numsession
from benefit b join
     membership_benefit mb
     on mb.benefitid = b.id and
        mb.membershipid = _membershipid and
        b.id =_benefitid
where b.id = _benefitid;
```

I speculate that you want one of these two things.

Comment: Won't your where clause in your second query result in that being an inner join?

Comment: @Andrew . . . Good catch.  I actually intended an inner join.